# Problems with JSF Using GlassFish

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish

[In case it is helpful, I am working from the book Core JavaServer Faces (3rd edition) and am on page 12, or thereabouts.]

I am trying to launch a JSF application using GlassFish but am having problems that I can't identify. I can start GlassFish correctly and see the screen that is depicted in the book, so that appears to be fine. I then copy the file login.war that I've created and placed in the directory containing the src and web directories for this project into the domains/domain1/autodeploy directory of GlassFish.

Going to `http://localhost:8080` in Chrome shows the correct screen; however `http://localhost:8080/login`, as described in the book and corresponding to the login.xhtml page that I have created, simply returns an HTTP 404 Error telling me 'The requested resource () is not available'.

My web.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/nx/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/we-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-patter>/faces/*</url-patter>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
</web-app>
```

Can anyone offer any help? I am using the Eclipse IDE, my version of GlassFish, as detailed on the error page described above, is 3.1.2.2. If there is any more information that would be helpful, e.g. directory structures, please do ask me for it.

Thanks, Conor.

Comment: Can you show the web.xml file of your application ?

Comment: I've added my web.xml into the post above. It's wroth emphasising that I don't actually know what should be in there so I may well have it wrong.

Comment: try adding `<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
  </context-param>` and access http://localhost:8080/login.jsf

Comment: Ok, a few pages later in the book it explained what the web.xml file should look like - I'm a bit confused by this since it definitely says  'The application should start up at this point' after directing the user to navigate to the second link I provided (does this suggest anything, e.g. is what I'm seeing correct behaviour, given what they've said)? I have changed my web.xml to the one in the book, and also included context-param you gave me but I still get the same result. Any ideas?

Comment: @yodamad: Do you own the book? The `http://localhost:8080/login` example in the book is not a Facelet file. It's the context root of the webapp (which in turn should implicitly open the `<welcome-file>` as declared in `web.xml`). The statement/expectation of the OP that it explicitly opens `/login.xhtml` is misleading. @ConorW: it may help to take a JSF pause and learn basic Servlets so that you get a better grasp on this kind of basic Servlet API stuff.

Comment: What's a good book on basic servlets?

Comment: @BalusC No I don't have the book. Just answer on my knowledge. If login is the context-root, it may be use like this http://localhost:8080/login/ ending by / ?

Answer (score 1):

You should set your application `context-root` to `login` if you need to access it with `http://localhost:8080/login`. There are several ways how to do it, e.g. check this [Glassfish tip](http://alexismp.wordpress.com/2007/08/30/glassfish-tip-have-your-application-be-the-root-application/) or in Eclipse IDE, in project Properties click on Web Project Settings and enter new Context root of your application.
This is not a bug, so until you will run more then one application on your server, you can leave it this way if you wish.